# dynamic subsetting in r

Tags: r, subset

I have a data set that is something like the following, but with many more columns and rows:

```
a<-c("Fred","John","Mindy","Mike","Sally","Fred","Alex","Sam")
b<-c("M","M","F","M","F","M","M","F")
c<-c(40,35,25,50,25,40,35,40)
d<-c(9,7,8,10,10,9,5,8)
df<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
colnames(df)<-c("Name", "Gender", "Age", "Score")
```

I need to create a function that will let me sum the scores for selected subsets of the data.  However, the subsets selected may have different numbers of variables each time.  One subset could be `Name=="Fred"` and another could be `Gender == "M"` & `Age == 40`.  In my actual data set, there could be up to 20 columns used in a selected subset, so I need to make this as general as possible.

I tried using a sapply command that included `eval(parse(text=...)`, but it takes a long time with only a sample of 20,000 or so records.  I'm sure there's a much faster way, and I'd appreciate any help in finding it.

Comment: I guess it will depend on what you find to be a flexible representation of a filter, e.g. `list(Gender = "M", Age = 40)`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to represent these two variables.  One way is as two distinct objects, another is as two elements in a list.

However, using a `named list` might be the easiest:

```
# df is a function for the F distribution.  Avoid using "df" as a variable name
DF <- df

example1 <- list(Name = c("Fred"))  # c() not needed, used for emphasis
example2 <- list(Gender = c("M"), Age=c(40, 50))

## notice that the key portion is `DF[[nm]] %in% ll[[nm]]`

subByNmList <- function(ll, DF, colsToSum=c("Score")) {
    ret <- vector("list", length(ll))
    names(ret) <- names(ll)
    for (nm in names(ll))
        ret[[nm]] <- colSums(DF[DF[[nm]] %in% ll[[nm]] , colsToSum, drop=FALSE])

    # optional
    if (length(ret) == 1)
        return(unlist(ret, use.names=FALSE))

    return(ret)
   }

subByNmList(example1, DF)
subByNmList(example2, DF)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lapply( subset( df, Gender == "M" & Age == 40, select=Score), sum)
#$Score
#[1] 18
```

I could have writtne just :

```
sum( subset( df, Gender == "M" & Age == 40, select=Score) )
```

But that would not generalize very well.